# JPA - Retrieving records from various entities that share the same ForeignKey after an ID is passed in at the API

Tags: spring, jpa, jpql, joincolumn

Consider the following dummy data entities and its defined relationships:

**Entity Business**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "business")
public class Business {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
public Long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "Business")
public List<GiveMoney> giveMoney;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "Business")
public List<RandomForm> randomForm;

@Column(name = "name")
public String name;

--  other fields & getters and setters omitted --
```

**Entity GiveMoney**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "give_money")
public class GiveMoney{


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
public Long id;

@ManyToOne
Business business;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "random_form_id", insertable = false, updatable = false, 
referencedColumnName = "id")
public RandomForm randomForm;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "person_giving_money_id", insertable = false, updatable = 
false, 
referencedColumnName = "id")
public PersonGivingMoney personGivingMoney;

@Column(name = "business_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Long business_id;

@Column(name = "person_giving_money_id")
public Integer person_giving_money_id;

@Column(name = "random_form_id")
public Integer  random_form_id;

@Column(name = "how_much")
public Integer howMuch;

--  other fields & getters and setters omitted --
```

**Entity RandomForm**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "random_form")
public class RandomForm{

@ManyToOne
Business business

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
public Long id;

@Column(name = "business_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Long business_id;

--  other fields & getters and setters omitted --
```

I've left out the final entity, personGivingMoney as it would only hold an Id which is referenced by person_giving_money_id and name.

Please excuse the underscores, possibly incorrect insertable/updateable values and waste of space through unnecessary @Column annotations

Naturally, when I execute a getAll in my controller on the List GiveMoney It would retrieve a full list along with the joined columns from their respective entity.

This is the findByBusiness_id in the **GiveMoneyRepo**

```
    List<GiveMoney> findByBusiness_id(Long id);
```

and **controller**

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/test/{id}")
public List<GiveMoney>findAllWithGivenBusinessId(@PathVariable Long id){
    return giveMoneyRepo.findByBusiness_id(id);
 }
```

As expected, it would filter the GiveMoney list and return all records that hold the given business id at the api, *however* it would at the same time return random records from the RandomForm entity and PersonGivingMoney entity in the same result set. I believe this is normal because I've just specified my condition on the GiveMoney list through the GiveMoney repository, without telling Spring what to do with the rest of the entities/records.

Both RandomForm and GiveMoney hold the business_id as a ForeignKey, I would like to give a business id in at the API and retrieve a list that would show the correct records from both entities based on the given id. Simply said:

FindGiveMoneyByBusiness_Id & FindRandomFormByBusiness_id into one JPA query & resultset.

I've read the documentation but clearly not well enough as Im sure Spring JPA has a way of doing this, alternatively I suppose I could be looking at creating a nativeQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Solved - after a few hours of staring at the screan I realized that my relation ships were not set up properly. After setting them up correctly I was able to match records with one ID and one method due to the join.